# Usage of test_commit and test_pull_requests in rosdistro file

Tags: ros, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where can we find the usage of `test_commits` and `test_pull_requests` tags in rosdistro file?

Looking at [rep-0143](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0143.html#distribution-file) they look so useful. However, after I turned test_pull_requests on [for a package](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/11773/files), I've not seen nor received anything regarding pull requests with ROS buildfarm. Are we supposed to get emails? Or is the github PR page supposed to get updated? Or is there specific website to look at about the result?

And I wanted to document this once I resolve this question, but where's the best place to be? I'm inclined to change the title of [this wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/ChangeBuildFlags) so that it can talk a bit more general stuff about rosdistro usage.

[Related question](http://answers.ros.org/question/236406/default-bool-value-for-test_commits-and-test_pull_requests-in-rosdistro-format)

---

Update 7/11/2016

> you need to give the GitHub user used by Jenkins access to setup web hooks

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, nor the wiki page that says the following:

> The GitHub org unit where the repository is located must grant access to the user ros-pull-request-builder in order to allow Jenkins to setup the necessary web hooks.

What is `grant access` here might be my question. On `https://github.com/%OUR_ORG%/%REPO%/settings/collaboration`, I just gave a `write` access to [ros-pull-request-builder](https://github.com/ros-pull-request-builder) to our repo, which I feel a little too much. but since the repo is open to public granting `read` access doesn't make sense to me. Could you be specific about what needs to be done?

---

Update2 7/11/2016

Sorry but still not sure.

- I gave @ros-pull-request-builder an admin access. Then add a comment `@ros-pull-request-builder retest this please` in a pull request.
- (Though nt sure if this is right thing to do) Also I added the following at `https://github.com/%OUR_ORG%/%REPO%/settings/hooks`, with jenkins url `http://jenkins.ros.org:8080/github-webhook`

  - Jenkins (GitHub plugin)
  - Jenkins (Git plugin)

I don't see anything happens, and on the github hook page, both of the above is indicated as "This hook has never been triggered`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239060/usage-of-test_commit-and-test_pull_requests-in-rosdistro-file/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2016-07-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-07-11**:
When you change the permission it doesn't retrigger Jenkins to try to establish the webhook. Please add a link to the job and I can manually reconfigure it. Otherwise it happens automatically every night.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-07-11**:
The two webhooks you manually created look incorrect. I would not recommend trying to configure that manually but let Jenkins handle the webhook creation.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-07-12**:
Sorry I tried but couldn't spot the job on http://jenkins.ros.org:8080. The PR I'm testing is https://github.com/tork-a/rtmros_nextage/pull/242 if that helps.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-07-12**:
Are you referring to this job: http://build.ros.org/view/Ipr/job/Ipr__rtmros_nextage__ubuntu_trusty_amd64/ If yes, the `ros-pull-request-builder` use has no permissions on that org unit and therefore can't setup the webhook.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-07-12**:
If you rely on your manual webhook you might want to look at https://developer.github.com/webhooks/testing/ on how to test if it works. Btw. the server is build.ros.org and not jenkins.ros.org (which is only a redirect).

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-07-13**:
Turned out that the server's URL was the key for me. Now webhook seems to have been triggered. Thank you Dirk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of the `bloom` tutorials describes the process to enable pull request jobs for your repo: http://wiki.ros.org/buildfarm/Pull%20request%20testing

I assume you are missing the `1.1 Prerequisite` a step. You need to give the GitHub user used by Jenkins access to setup web hooks to notify Jenkins about pull requests and changes to them.

**Update:** I have updated the wiki page with a reference to the Jenkins plugin and repeating the requirements documented there.

> Jenkins uses the [Pull Request Builder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin) to setup the webhooks which trigger Jenkins for new or updated pull requests and report back the status.
> Therefore the GitHub org unit where the repository is located must grant push, pull and administrative rights to the user ros-pull-request-builder.
> (You can setup the webhook manually to avoid the need for administrative rights.
> Then the Jenkins user only  needs push and pull access.)

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-07-11**:
Thanks, I updated OP to ask a bit further.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-07-11**:
I updated the answer.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-07-11**:
Hm, still trying. I added "Update2" in my op for more question.